# Allowing customer groups with identical name

Tags: import, customer-group

I have special case where I need to allow to create customer groups with a name that already exists.

This is done through an import where we're able to differentiate between groups with the same name by extending table `customer_group` with a new column for `external_id`.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the customer group name constraint is enforced on the code level and not on the DB itself. I didn't spend too much time, but looking at `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`, take a look at method `save()` which calls `_checkUnique()` that throws an exception for non-unique customer group name (see around line 676 on 1.9.2).

This can be overcome by using direct SQL or the Zend DB adapter, and since `customer_group` table is so simple, it should be easy and safe. I would use the latter.